# User Authenication not working in Safari

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have this code on a breakpoint, it works in every browser except Safari on Windows, when I log in, it always shows that the user is not authenticated.

I reset Safari to default.

In My web.Config file I added

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" defaultUrl="~/ToolsHome.aspx" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

Can't get safari to work.

I didn't specify a cookie name? I'm running this on local host and then when I upload it to my domain, same problem.

```
if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
else
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Physician") 
        || HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Staff"))
    {
         if (Session["loggedin"] != null)
         {
              Session["PatientID"] = Session["loggedin"].ToString();
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a late answer, but I had this problem to. I solved it by adding cookieless="UseCookies" to the forms-tag in web.config. When you use Chrome in iOS or Safari in a built in app on Mac the auth-cookies was dropped.

This only happens in NET4.0 and are solved if you upgrade to NET4.5.

For more information, read this article:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FormsAuthenticationOnASPNETSitesWithTheGoogleChromeBrowserOnIOS.aspx